# Ranges with a parameter

Tags: ruby

```
def crazynum(number)

  sum = [0..number.length]
  sum.select do |i|
     if ((i%3 == 0) || (i %5 == 0)) && !((i%3 == 0) && (i %5 == 0))
       array<<i
     end
  end

  puts array.inspect

end

puts crazynum(10)
```

How can I use ranges such as `(1..number.length)`? with `select` or `each` methods?

Can someone explain to me why I am getting the following error please?

```
$ ruby crazy_select.rb
crazy_select.rb:3:in `crazynum': undefined method `length' for 10:Fixnum
(NoMethodError)
from crazy_select.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

Comment: The main problem you have is that you try to call `length` on number, which, as you see, does't work. You're also using `select` method incorrectly.

Comment: Different brackets denote different objects. `(a..b)` creates a range, whereas `[a..b]` creates an array (containing a range).

Comment: Assuming you're after fizz or buzz and not fizzbuzz, then your conditional is at least correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're only after *fizzes (multiples of 3)*, *buzzes (multiples of 5)* and not *fizzbuzzes (multiples of 3 and 5)*, then I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
def crazynum(n)
  array=[]
  (1..n).each do |i|
    if ( i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0 ) && !( i%3 == 0 && i%5 == 0 )
      array << i
    end
  end
  p array
end

crazynum(10) #=> [3, 5, 6, 9, 10]
#to check an example of fizzbuzz doesn't appear
crazynum(16) #=> [3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12]
```

Or if you want to use `select` try:

```
def crazynum(n)
  (1..n).select do |i|
    ( i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0 ) && !( i%3 == 0 && i%5 == 0 )
  end
end

p crazynum(10) #=> [3, 5, 6, 9, 10]
#to check an example of fizzbuzz doesn't appear
p crazynum(16) #=> [3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12]
```